# Retrieve number of the day sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I wan't to retrieve the number of the day using an SQL request but I found that I retrieve the number of day since the 01-01-4712 using this query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE),'J') FROM DUAL;
```

Is there any other query I may use?

Comment: `since the 01-01-4712`? Doctor Brown is that you?

Comment: Just "The Doctor", thank you very much ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `to_char()` to convert your date.  Format mask 'DDD' returns the day of the year.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'DDD') from dual;

select to_char(to_date('1/1/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'DDD') from dual;
```

Some more info on various formats: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php

Answer (score 0):

After investigations I found that we can use this query to obtain the number of day in the current year:

```
select to_date(sysdate) - trunc(sysdate,'YYYY') from dual
```

Comment: I'm afraid that answer is wrong, as it returns yesterday's day of the year. What's wrong with "select to_char(sysdate, 'DD') from dual;" to get today's day of the year? Since you are using SYSDATE, I'm assuming you want today's day of the year?